# Prevent textbox control being posted from web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form that displays data I get from a webservice.  There is a textbox `mainComments` that holds all comments previously added through a winform front end. Very occasionally this data contains text that causes and error `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`.  Truth is I am not interested in the contents of this textbox on the form submit. Although I know I could solve my problem by not displaying this data in textbox, for whatever reason the requirement is to keep the textbox.  The textbox is readonly and there to display data only.

My question is:  Is there any way I can isolate this textbox and prevent it being posted as part of the submit? Something like `mainComments.IncludeInFormSubmit = false;` or stop just this textbox being validated and prevent the `HttpRequestValidationException` being thrown.  I really do not want to turn the feature off for the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a plain HTML `textarea` tag instead of an `asp:textbox` tag.

### Example

```
<textarea>
    <%= mainComments %>
</textarea>
```

**instead** of something like this

```
<asp:TextBox id="tbComments" rows="5" Text="mainComments" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" />
```

Comment: As I said in the question I know I could replace the control to solve the problem but the requirement is I keep the control even though they can give me no valid reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround which you can use, set disabled="disabled" for that control and it will be excluded from postback. and you can enable it when required.

Comment: This disables the scroll bar for the control as well.

Comment: disable it from javascript when you click the submit button then. If you aren't willing to disable it or swap it out with a non-form control, then sorry. You are out of luck.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen I would swap it out as I don't see the point in it being a textbox, it serves no purpose, but unfortunatly my hands a tied.  However your idea of disabling on click may be a work around.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen I took your idea and changed it slightly. On click on button I validate the form and if it validates I clear the offending textbox just before the form submits.  All working corrently even if it is a nasty workaround :) Thanks

Comment: @Fred - If your hands are tied for no particulary good reason, I would have no problems using a nasty workaround myself. Good to hear it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode when you set the value to the textbox?

Another option would be to not use a textbox at all and just use CSS to mark it up to look like it is in a textbox if that is the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Simply disable the textbox... as below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="False" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: This disables the scroll bar for the control as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can only turn off input validation for the entire page. The only solution I can think of is to turn off the input validation, and then check all the other input fields.